# is there any way to install smart.json dependencies using meteor cli?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

Since Meteor 0.9.0 it's posible to install dependencies from atmospherejs just using the meteor cli without install meteorite package manager.

However, is it posible to install all the dependencies declared in smart.json file without install meteorite (i.e. just using meteor cli)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`smart.json` is no longer used since Meteor 0.9. The dependencies of an app are stored in `.meteor/packages`, and are automatically installed when you run `meteor run`, and when the app restarts automatically after its files are changed. That is, the meteor tool will update the package catalog and install updated packages automatically.